# Make function parametres Case insensitive in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, case-insensitive

Here is my function:

```
def run_test_non_compilation(short_name,error_label)

@short_name = short_name

$error_label =  error_label

# more coding here
 end
```

What I want is as follows:

- If I execute

> run_test_non_compilation('MDL_ConfigRS001',"HKI_load_cnf")

It should give  the same result as if i called my function using

> run_test_non_compilation('MDL_ConfigRS001',"hki_load_cnf")

or

> run_test_non_compilation('MDL_ConfigRS001',"hki_LOAD_cnf")

etc...

The variable `error_label` must be case insensitive when using it inside the function.

Comment: Why do you use `$error_label` and `$log_file_name` global variables? If I understand context correctly, they should be local variables. General principle in Ruby is to avoid using global variables if you can.

Comment: @MarekLipka: yeah, I foresee some hard debugging sessions if this goes on :)

Comment: I actually cannot. I already did, but you got at least 2 down votes, so mine is bringing you UP to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case insensitive comparison can be done with [String#casecmp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-casecmp) :

```
if($error_label.casecmp(some_string) == 0) {
  # do stuff
end
```

To be clear, there is *no way* to make a string variable become case insensitive in Ruby.  You can compare a string using `some_string.casecmp(some_other_string)`.  This will return `0` if the strings are the same, ignoring case.

Second, you don't really want to put that in a global variable.  Are you maybe a PHP developer? It's common when moving from PHP to Ruby to make global ($) vars when you intend to use instance vars (@).

Regardless, knowing what you intend to do with the string would help a great deal.  If you expect to take any case of the string, and find some configuration file on a case sensitive file system, you'd have to enumerate the configuration names then do something like `config_array.select {|a| $error_label.casecmp(a) == 0 }` where config_array is something like ['HKI_load_cnf'] and that is the true capitalization. I don't know though, I'm really grasping to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you check if your `error_label` is present in your file. To make it case-insensitive, just use `match` and pass into it `Regexp` ignoring case:

```
if line.match(/#{error_label}/i)
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it does not work, because in fact downcase it convert all upercases to lowercases and this not what i want i want the parameter $error_label to be case insensitive eg :  if i pass the argument  HKI_load_cnf it will be same as hki_Load_cnf or hki_LOAD_Cnf or Hki_LOad_cNF you see what i want

Comment: @Mourad I think you need to be a little bit expressive. What happens after you tried it? How exactly does your code look like now?

Comment: what i want i want the parameter $error_label to be case insensitive eg : if i pass the argument HKI_load_cnf it will be same as hki_Load_cnf or hki_LOAD_Cnf or Hki_LOad_cNF you see what i want

Comment: @Mourad it was quite hard to understand what you mean, but I think I managed to do it. I edited my answer. On a side note: I guess you should learn some Ruby basics before writing more complicated applications.